# Video emotion API incredibly slow

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I submitted a 5 minutes video, and after almost one hour still no results.

A couple of question:

Is the service internally analysing each frame (and they are a lot in a 5 minutes video!) using image emotion API, or some other algorithm (maybe taking advantage of motions etc) is employed?

Any chance that it will be speed up in the future? Maybe depending on the chosen plan?

Comment: me too. I just use the sample Windows Form https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Video-Windows and use just 5 seconds 3 mb mp4, it runs eternally and never came back with result.

Answer (score 0):

The Video API, including Emotion, has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/emotion/emotion-api-how-to-topics/howtocallemotionforvideo) since October 30th, 2017.